# C# JSON.Net CustomCreationConverter with parent object

Tags: c#, json, json.net

How do I extract via the Deserialization the payload of the returned json response that is encapsulated within the `data` object of the response?

This is the json response:

```
  {"data":{"status":"ok","created_at":"2017-05-26 17:34:12.224524Z","app_version":1.0,"api_version":1.0}}
```

My Converter Class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;

namespace Sample.Models
{
    class StatusConverter : CustomCreationConverter<Status>
    {
        public override Status Create(Type objectType)
        {

            return new Status();
        }
     }
}
```

My Model for `Status`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace Sample.Models
{

    class Status
    {
        [JsonProperty("app_version")]
        public string AppVersion { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("api_version")]
        public string APIVersion { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("status")]
        public string CurrentStatus { get; set; }

    }
}
```

API Call using `RestClient`

```
    public void checkConnectivityStatus()
    {
        var client = new RestClient(BaseUrl);

        var request = new RestRequest("status", Method.GET);

        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
        var content = response.Content; // raw content as string
        Status status = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Status>(content, new StatusConverter());
        Console.Write(status.AppVersion);
    }
```

Edit: Updating the Model

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace Sample.Models
{
    public interface IStatus
    {
        string AppVersion { get; set; }

        string APIVersion { get; set; }

        string CurrentStatus { get; set; }
    }

    [JsonObject]
    class Status : IStatus
    {
        [JsonProperty("app_version")]
        public string AppVersion { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("api_version")]
        public string APIVersion { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("status")]
        public string CurrentStatus { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Comment: How do you extra? That's not a question, if you mean extract and `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` doesn't work, please State the error or describe what's not working

Comment: Extract. Typo. I'll fix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need a wrapper object for your response.

```
public class DeserializedResponse 
{
     [JsonProperty("data")]
     public Status Status { get; set; }
}
```

And then use it like so:

```
//var content = {"data":{"status":"ok","created_at":"2017-05-26 17:34:12.224524Z","app_version":1.0,"api_version":1.0}}

var deserializedResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DeserializedResponse>(content);

Debug.Assert(deserializedResponse.Status.CurrentStatus == "ok");
```

Comment: If all my objects come in the wrapper `data` class, how do I have it extra that `data` for each?

Comment: @DogEatDog I think you should create a wrapper object for each